# Can't connect to snap servers

Tags: networking, snap

This is my first time setting up a server, and I'm already facing a huge Problem: I can't install software via snap! I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu server.

When I try to `sudo snap install Nextcloud`, or anything else(like refreshing snapd) i get this response:

```
error: cannot install "nextcloud": persistent network error: Post
"https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh": dial tcp 185.125.188.59:443: connect: network is unreachable
```

I tried disabling ufw, deleting the proxy using `sudo snap unset system proxy.https` and `sudo snap unset system proxy.https`

When i ping snapcraft.io, it's valid, but api.snapcraft.io is unreachable.

Comment: It happens from time to time. Just wait.

Comment: guess the problem most likely is in the network. Maybe you are using a proxy? Or there are some limits on your network? Anyway, the first necessary step is to be able to ping to `api.snapcraft.io`. btw, are you in China? ifso, you may need a VPN to access to the network

Comment: Ok so I tried it several times and it still doesn't work. The issue isn't just with snapcraft. It's with many different installers like Minecraft or steam. I can't ping java.net, but i can ping java.com. i tried disabling the firewall, DNS is set to googles 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 and no, I am not in China

Comment: @Joosl I have the same issue. Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: @DanieleB Yes, you have to specify the routers ip adress / gateway in the netplan config
https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/netplan-tutorial/#showing-your-current-netplan-configuration

Comment: @Joosl I found out in my case the reason was the server just had an IPv6 address, and not IPv4 address. Currently Snap doesn't support IPv6 addresses:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapstore-server/+bug/1710022
So, I had to take an IPv4 address